# JS+REST+NodeJS: How to parse a JSON list from a JSON object

Tags: javascript, python, json, rest, express

In Python I have a JSON object, inside its fields there is one (**field3**) which contains a list of json objects.

This object is passed from a Python script to a REST service based in JS with Express framework:

```
urllib.request.urlopen(
    urllib.request.Request(
    url="http://"+self.__host+_":"+self.__port+"/api"+restmethod,
    data=urllib.parse.urlencode(objData).encode('utf8'),
    headers=self.__headertoken,method=httpmethod)
)
```

But when the server receives the JSON automatically recognizes the **field33** as a string instead of a JSON list.

```
{ field1: '',
  field2: '',
  field3: '[{\'field31\': \'\', \'field32\': \'\', \'field33\':\'\',\'field34\': \'\', \'field34\': \'0.00\'}]',
  field4: ''
}
```

So when I try **obj.field3[0]** it returns a string rather than JSON list.

I tried `JSON.parse(string)` and `JSON.stringify(object)` but still I cannot access to the Json list and its elements like **obj.field3.field31**

How can I recover that JSON list from the parent JSON field?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`field3` should be:

```
'[{\"field31\": \"\",...}]',
```

or simply:

```
'[{"field31": "",...}]',
```

single quote `'` will cause error when parsed by JSON.parse.

And `obj.field3` is a array, so to get the `field31` value, you should use:

`obj.field3[0].field31`

Comment: Thanks @yangguang. Just to complete the answer I set this line of code before parsing the string into JSON object: 
`var jsonlist = JSON.parse(objOrder.items.replace(/'/g,"\""))`